# How can I change the color of a progress bar value in HTML?

Tags: css, html, progress-bar

```css
progress {
  border: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  background: crimson;
}

progress {
  color: lightblue;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: lightblue;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: lightcolor;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <progress min="0" max="100" value="63" />
</div>
```

I have tried nearly everything, but the value color of the progress bar remains the same. The only browser that is responsive to a change is IE. Firefox allows to change background color only. Chrome doesn't show anything at all. Can you spot what is wrong with my code?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Comment: By default this is styled by the OS/browser, but you can override it with ie. `-webkit-appearance` (see https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/#article-header-id-4)

Comment: typo in `-moz-progress-bar`? lighcolor=lightblue? 
But works for me in Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/t0znpjht/

Comment: You want to replace default background of `progress` (gray color by default), yes?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov no, I want to change the color of progress bar value

Comment: @CeeJay `background: lightblue;` works in Chrome. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov well it works in IE and now in Firefox as well. As for Chrome it shows nothing literally - blank screen...

Comment: @CeeJay Does [RenzoCC's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45508152/1548895) answer work for you?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I still got issues with Chrome though but other browsers seem to work fine now

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```css
progress {
  border: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  background: crimson;
}

progress {
  color: lightblue;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: lightblue;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: red;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
It will work on webkit browser, like this example

<div>
  <progress min="0" max="100" value="63" />
</div>
```

Comment: why have you color property in another CSS rule, it can be put in first one also, right?

Comment: why is there twice "progress::-webkit-progress-value {}"?

Comment: it is not necessary to have "progress:-webkist-progress-value" twice, the answer has been updated

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making your own progress bar, you can simply use the [**`accent-color`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color) variable instead of `color` or `background`.

```css
progress {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
}

.colored {
  accent-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Default: <progress min="0" max="100" value="63" /></p>
  <p>Colored: <progress class="colored" min="0" max="100" value="63" /></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

it's pretty limited as to what you can dom but this this must do the trick

```
progress {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar-value {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: orangered;
}
```

Comment: `::-webkit-progress-bar-value` is invalid

Answer (score -3):

use this

accent-color:"#fff

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.